# replaceAll function : Script too long to execute

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code :

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace){
    if(!replace){
        return this;
    }

    while(this.indexOf(search) !== false){
        this.replace(search, replace);
    }

    return this;
};
```

I guess it should work, however it doesn't.

The code should work like this :

```
var x="hihi";
x.replaceAll("hi", "i");
```

And finally the value of x should be :

```
ii
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer doing this.

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replace) {
    var str = this;
    var pos = str.indexOf(search);
    while (pos > -1) {
        str = str.replace(search, replace);
        pos = str.indexOf(search);
    }
    return (str);
};
```

But in your case you must replace the "!== false" for "> -1" and return from " this.replace(search, replace);" you must put in a variable, because the "replace" function doesn't change the value of "this" and just returns the new string value.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve what you want using the builtin replace function but appending the g flag to the regex
i.e.

```
var x="hihi";
x='hihi'.replace(/hi/g, 'i');
```

Answer (score 0):

`String#replace` returns a *new* string; thus `this` will never change. What you need to do is also return a new string, as strings (i think) are immutable.

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace){
    if(!replace){
        return this;
    }
    var str = this;

    while(~str.indexOf(search)){ // indexOf() doesn't return false
        str = str.replace(search, replace);
    }

    return str;
};
```

Also, note that it is [unadvised to modify native prototypes](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/).

Answer (score 0):

And I've found that this method is better :

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace){
    if(!replace){
        return this;
    }

    return this.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replace);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the bitwise not operator in conjuction with `indexOf`

```
var a = ~'foo'.indexOf('o'), //-2, evaluates to true
    b = ~'foo'.indexOf('x'); // 0, evaluates to false
```

`-1` will evaluate to false, since `~-1 === 0`, but any positive indexes will return a negative number, which evaluates to `true`. Thus, you can simply do

```
while(~this.indexOf(search))
```

or even

```
while(!!~this.indexOf(search))
```

for a true boolean value (which isn't required).